# Change Windows non AD password from linux

Tags: linux, windows, password

How can I change a windows non-ad password from linux command line? I have access to the Admin account on the windows server 2016. The two server are not the same machine and I do not search for a linux boot dvd.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but these answers have some options for you: http://serverfault.com/questions/638659/managing-windows-powershell-from-linux-terminal

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That are some good answers, but RDP and WebAccess can not be automated so easily on a linux server without gui. And I didnt find any stable SSH Server for Windows

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest go with hiren's boot cd:

- http://broexperts.com/how-to-resetrecover-windwos-8-1-with-hirens-bootcd/
- http://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-reset-lost-windows-password-with-hirens-bootcd/

It requires reboot to perform password reset.

Comment: @MrRaspberry see my edit